# I can't bind [href] with my variable value

Tags: angular

On anchor click i need to open mail client. I have a function that returns the HTML from the component ts file.

This is working - when i click i get opened mail client

```
infoWindowContent() {
   return `<div>
        <a href="mailto:someone@example.com">
          <button class='dispatcher-send-mail-btn'>Send Email</button>
        </a>
      </div>`
}
```

but when i have mailto: with some varible that holds the value then it is not working

```
let emailDefault = 'someone@example.com';
```

```
 <div>
        <a [href]="'mailto:' + emailDefault">
          <button class='dispatcher-send-mail-btn'>Send Email</button>
        </a>
      </div>
```

Comment: This isn't how you're supposed to use HTML in the component. Typically, the tags would be defined in the template and only the `emailDefault` will be initialized in the component controller. Perhaps there is a better way of what you're attempting. Please provide more code on how `infoWindowContent()` function is triggered and how is it's return value used in the template?

Comment: I must return like this. I am using google maps API and showing infoWindowContent.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59890565/how-to-open-email-application-while-clicking-on-the-email-id-in-google-maps-info

Comment: But i tried having pure HTML in the template and bind to the component property.Again it does not work

Comment: In that case try: `<a href="mailto:${emailDefault}">` instead of concatenation using `+`.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But why binding is not working ? And why the concatanation was a problem ?

Comment: I've posted an answer. Perhaps that would provide more insight into why the concatenation wasn't working.

Comment: I accepted your answer and i undertand that. But the binding as core conecpt when we do [href] = "variableName" it shold take that value and bind it . For example it works with [src] why not now  ?

Comment: And template literals are - ` ` - how it works in "" here in angular

Comment: Binding `[src]` or `[href]` in the template is handled by the Angular's rendering engine. It replaces the RHS variables with it's corresponding values. When you're attempting `\`<a [href]="'mailto:' + emailDefault">\`` in the controller, it's pure JS and it's engine evaluates `emailDefault` as just that. A string `emailDefault`, a plain string. That is why you need to use `${}` to tell JS that you'd like to evaluate it's contents as expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding from my comments, you could use dollar sign and  curly-braces `${}` expression to have placeholders in a [JS template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). So instead of trying concatenation using `+`, you could do

```js
infoWindowContent() {
  return `
    <div>
      <a href="mailto:${emailDefault}">
        <button class='dispatcher-send-mail-btn'>Send Email</button>
      </a>
    </div>
  `;
}
```